# Install an apk through flutter android

Tags: flutter, installation, apk

I have a flutter app that downloads an apk file. How can I install this file automatically through the flutter app on android and IOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out file.open() from dart:io doesn't open apk files, I used the package `open_file` and it worked.